# WordPress - 'The Loop' to show all posts, instead posts the title of the home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started with a  wordpress tutorial series and one of the first things it does was make a simple "the loop", to print the title and description of all of the posts. When I did it though, it prints the name and description of the home page.

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) 
 {
  while ( have_posts() ) 
    {
        the_post(); 
        the_title('<h2><a href="the_permalink();"','</a></h2>');   
        the_content(); 
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
 } // end if
?>
```

I cannot figure out why it prints the home page information instead of post info.

Comment: Where did you placed that code? If you want to display all post title and content, you should consider the global variable $post.

Comment: That was the entire index file. I was following a video tutorial and they were able to get it to work with just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display wordpress posts on any page , you need to pass the arguments as the following in the WP_Query and then loop them via object.

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Comment: Ok that make more sense. I was wondering where the_post was getting it's info from. I'm just a little confused as I was following a video tutorial that did it without the need of making a new object.

Comment: Actually the_post will by default fetch the front page (which is generally your home page) information first. If you want to display your posts on the home page , then you can do that by changing the reading option to blog from settings panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    require_once 'wp-config.php';
                    global $wpdb;
                    global $post;
                    $aasha_carousel_items = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'aasha_carousel_items',
                        'posts_per_page' => '5'
                    ));

                    // The Loop
                    if ( $aasha_carousel_items->have_posts() ) {
                        $count = 0;
                        $active = 'active';
                        echo '<div class="carousel-inner">';
                        while ( $aasha_carousel_items->have_posts() ) {
                            $aasha_carousel_items->the_post();

........
........
                        $count++;
                        $active = '';

                        }
                        echo '</div>';
                        /* Restore original Post Data */
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    } else {
                        // no posts found

}
```